# Whenever I add a specific script in the <head> section i lose my background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

to my `<head>` section my background colors disappear. Note that I am trying to make collapsible blocks and used code from w3schools to help.

Content in collapsible block in `<body>`:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h2>MENU // SOUPS</h2>
            <p>Blank</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h2>MENU // BEEF</h2>
            <p>Blank</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My background color code:

```
body {
  background-color: #dc143c;
}
```

Comment: Where is your snippet code? Not w3School!

Comment: How do you set background-color? Provide SO Snippet with issue

Comment: Is there a reason why you need jQuery mobile? If not, try to remove lines 2 and 4. Also, it is a good practice to put all your js files at the bottom of your html file (not in the head). In any case, jQuery should be the first thing to include and all other scripts should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery.mobile{-version}(.min).css` adds `CSS` style rules to your page.
You can override them, using more specific selectors (or equally specific, as long as your stylesheet loads after the `jquery.mobile` one).

To better understand `CSS` specificity, you could start from [`MDN's resource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on the subject. Please note they also provide other links with more information.

Working example, (your specific case):

```css
body.ui-overlay-a {
  background-color: #dc143c;
}
div.ui-page-theme-a  {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* this removes the box-shadow from selected element, as per your comment */
div.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
   <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h2>MENU // SOUPS</h2>
      <p>Blank</p>
   </div>
   <div data-role="collapsible">
       <h2>MENU // BEEF</h2>
       <p>Blank</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Quite welcome (to [so]). Happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::)

Comment: But now my Navigation Bar text is blurry, do you know any solutions for that?

Comment: By *"is blurry"* you mean it has a blue-ish border when selected? You need `div.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn:focus {box-shadow: none}` to remove that. It's all `CSS`. Learn to inspect elements, so you could build stronger selectors than the ones currently applying. Updated my answer, adding the code for it.

Comment: Sorry I went AFK for a while, but i came back and tried your new code but it still shows blue-ish border still shows up. Here an image: http://imgur.com/a/AOeup

Comment: I cannot tell you what's causing it if I can't inspect it. And I can't inspect pictures. Create a [mcve] if you need my help.

Comment: I made a new question more detailed if you could check it out it would be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562568/how-to-remove-blue-ish-outline-in-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<style>
body {
background-color: #dc143c !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

when using jquery-mobile, your body receives additional CSS classes, including **ui-overlay-a**, and your main div is wrapped in another div with class **ui-page-theme-a**.
Combined with your import of jquery-mobile default css file, your style is discarded by a more precise rule:

```
/* jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css:3 */
.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   ...
}
```

and
    .ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
       background-color: #f9f9f9;
       ...
    }

A fix would be to change your CSS to override this rule.
See [this snippet](https://jsbin.com/ficubosuyi/edit?html,css,output) as an example.

Cheers

Note: to investigate those issues, the best is to use your developer tools of your browser. See this page about [Chrome tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#dom-and-styles) as a start. The same exists for all browsers.