# How to remove blue-ish outline in navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A few hours back I asked a question on how my background disappeared when i added a collapsible list. The solution they gave me was:

```
 body.ui-overlay-a {
            background-color: #dc143c;
        }
        div.ui-page-theme-a  {
            background-color: transparent;
        }
```

I asked the same person about the blue box and he gave me this:

```
div.ui-page-theme-a  {
            background-color: transparent;
        }
```

But this didn't work does anyone have any answers?

Navigation bar code (CSS):

```
/* Navigation bar */
        .nav {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            margin-top: 20px;
            height: 40px;
            background: #000000;
        }

        .nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .nav ul li {
            list-style:  none;
        }

        .nav ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            float: right;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 50px;
            color: white;
        }

        .nav ul li a:hover {
            color: #D3D3D3;
        }

        .headerBreak {
            width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
        }

        h4 {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: right;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        p {
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
```

And this is the content inside the navigation bar (inside )

```
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Online Order</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="headerBreak"></div>
```

Note that this does not only apply to the navigation bar but also applies to my  and

Reference: [http://i.imgur.com/acnJE5Y.png](https://i.imgur.com/acnJE5Y.png)
Edit 1: I added this website to a free domain hoster, I have also added `outline: none;` to  `nav ul li a {` but it still doesnt work when i open itbut when I duplicate the file and I open it the text does not have the blue outline, but in my original file it does

http://marcxu88.000webhostapp.com

If you could inspect the code and see if what is wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you set up a demo please on CodePen? That would be quite helpful.

Comment: `jquery.mobile.css` is adding a `text-shadow` to your menu. Add  `div.ui-page-theme-a {text-shadow: none;}` to your `CSS`.

Comment: It removed the outline in the navigation bar thanks, i tried to add text-shadow: none; to p and h4 but it didn't seem to work do you know any solution for that, andnow how do I change the font back to what it originally was? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `outline: none;` to the selector `.nav ul li a`.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work :( I added my code to a free domain if you could please check it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing `text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;` from `.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper`